# Using a 3" display without connecting to GPIOs

Tags: gpio, hdmi, display

** I have no hardware experience so bear with me! I want to learn this stuff. A small background of my problem is below.

I'm looking to buy a 3" HDMI display, but my SPI pins will be taken by other hardware.

I understand I still need to hook up to a 5v pin and a ground for power, but does anyone know if I can just not use the other pins on the display. Can some of these screens still output on the screen while only plugged into the HDMI port and the 5v and ground pins?

I was looking at [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/3-5-LCD-Touch-Screen-Display-Module-USB-HDMI-1920x1080-RGB-For-Raspberry-Pi-3/222317839919?_trksid=p2047675.c100005.m1851&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIC.MBE%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D41404%26meid%3Dccc53f5dfba24310b81601dd6d4fafb9%26pid%3D100005%26rk%3D6%26rkt%3D6%26mehot%3Dpp%26sd%3D152301520646)(just as an example)

** I am undertaking a project that requires the use of a small, high quality display of around 3". I will be using all the SPI pins with some other hardware, so I have been looking for an HDMI or USB setup for the display. Most models in this category seem to attach to the GPIO pins anyways, they are also touch screen; I don't really need the touch aspect.

Answer (score 1):

HDMI displays do not by definition require a SPI connection.  I believe the ones out there for the Pi that do, use it to incorporate a touchscreen interface, which you've said you don't need.

You can plug the Pi into a normal HDMI TV or monitor and use it, so if you can find a 3" HDMI screen that should be fine.  You may have to tinker with settings in `/boot/config.txt` [as described here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/master/configuration/config-txt.md#hdmi-mode-options).